# Widget updates before service has ended

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I'm making an android widget which it is a button.

When click it, the widget lunch a service and service write changes in shared preferences, and then widget should call update method to change background depending of preference value changed in service.

The issue is that update method runs before service so widget updates last value stored in shared preferences before service change it.

WHAT I WANT: 
- Click on widget button
- OnReceive method
- call startService()
- service is running
- In service: edit shared reference
- service ends
- call update widgets depending of value of shared preference edited

WHAT REALLY WORKS:
- Click on widget button
- OnRecieved method
- call startService()
- call update widgets and updates depending of value of shared preference edited (but not edited yet )
-  service is running
- In service: edit shared reference
- service ends

My CODE: 
- OnReceive()
- in OnReceive():
--- startService();
--- updateWidgets();

How i could run service completely before update method start running????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startService() is not a blocking operation, so if you have startService() and updateWidgets() in sequence on onReceive(), it will not wait for the service to start and end to run updateWidgets().

To have the way you want, you need to call updateWidgets() in the end of your service startCommand() and also call finish() to end service.